# Manipulate multiple Python turtles defined inside a function

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

Here is the part of my code which I believe is the problem. With this in mind, I have two questions, the first is: "How can I manipulate multiple objects (Python turtles)?" which I am trying to solve with lists and `.append()`. This causes the following problem:

```
if enemy.index(enemy).ycor() < -100:
NameError: name 'enemy' is not defined
```

I think it has something to do with the impossibility (I presume) of defining a `Turtle` object inside a function. Which raises my second question, "How can I create a `Turtle` object inside a function?"

```
def spawn(t,shape,color,x,y):
        t = turtle.Turtle() 
        t.speed(0)
        t.up()
        t.goto(x,y)
        t.shape(shape)
        t.color(color)
def go_upx():
    if enemy.index(enemy).heading() != 90:
        enemy.index(enemy).seth(90) 

def go_downx():
    if enemy.index(enemy).heading() != 270:
        enemy.index(enemy).seth(270)

def go_leftx():
    if enemy.index(enemy).heading() != 180:
        enemy.index(enemy).seth(180)
def move():
    if enemy.index(enemy).heading() == 90:
        y = enemy.index(enemy).ycor()
        enemy.index(enemy).sety(y + 20)

    if enemy.index(enemy).heading() == 270:
        y = enemy.index(enemy).ycor()
        enemy.index(enemy).sety(y - 20)

    if enemy.index(enemy).heading() == 180:
        x = enemy.index(enemy).xcor()
        enemy.index(enemy).setx(x - 20)

def enemies_direction():
    en_direction = random.randint(1,3)
    if 1 == en_direction:
        go_upx()
    if 2 == en_direction:
        go_leftx()
    if 3 == en_direction:
        go_downx()

enemies = []
#Main Loop
while True:
    wn.update()
    for x in range(0,10):
        for enemy in enemies:
            randy = random.randint(-90,300)
            enemies.append(spawn(enemy.index(enemy),"circle","blue",490,randy))
            enemies_direction()
            if enemy.xcor<-600:
                enemy.pop(enemy.index(enemy))
    BgLimits()           
    move()
    time.sleep(delay)

wn.mainloop()
```

Comment: `spawn` should return the newly created turtle. The last line of the function should be `return t`.

Comment: Also, you need to pass a turtle object to all the other functions. For example: `def go_upx():` should be `def go_upx(enemy):`.

Comment: What is `enemy.index(enemy)` supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I create a turtle inside a function?

Turtles can be created inside functions or at the top level like other objects.  Your problems lie elsewhere in your code.  One caveat, turtles aren't garbage collected like other objects (they live forever on a list in the turtle library) so it's best to reuse them rather than continously spawn new ones.

> here we have the part of the code which is referred to the problem

Here's what I see are the problem**s** with this code:

```
while True:
```

There should never be a `while True:` inside an event driven environment like turtle -- use a timer event.

```
if enemy.xcor<-600:
```

Not proper Python turtle logic, this should be:

```
if enemy.xcor() < -600:
```

In this situation:

```
enemies.append(spawn(...))
```

as @JohnnyMopp mentions, `spawn()` returns `None` so `enemies` is a list of these.  You need to have `spawn()` return the new turtle.  Here:

```
enemy.pop(...)
```

You seem to be confusing your `enemy` iteration variable (a turtle) and your `enemies` global list of turtles.  (You can `pop()` a list, but not a turtle.)

Other problems include making a mixin of your initialization loop and your main loop -- two different loops.

Below is my best guess rework of what your code is trying to do:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from random import choice, randint

def spawn(shape, color, x, y):
    t = Turtle(shape, visible=False)
    t.speed('fastest')
    t.color(color)
    t.penup()
    t.goto(x, y)
    t.showturtle()

    return t

def go_upx(enemy):
    enemy.seth(90)

def go_downx(enemy):
    enemy.seth(270)

def go_leftx(enemy):
    enemy.seth(180)

def move(enemy):
    if enemy.heading() == 90:
        y = enemy.ycor()
        enemy.sety(y + 20)

    if enemy.heading() == 180:
        x = enemy.xcor()
        enemy.setx(x - 20)

    if enemy.heading() == 270:
        y = enemy.ycor()
        enemy.sety(y - 20)

def enemy_direction(enemy):
    direction_function = choice([go_upx, go_downx, go_leftx])

    direction_function(enemy)

wn = Screen()
wn.setup(640, 640)
wn.tracer(False)

enemies = []

for _ in range(10):
    rand_y = randint(-300, 300)
    enemy = spawn("circle", "blue", 300, rand_y)
    enemy_direction(enemy)
    enemies.append(enemy)

def move_all():

    for enemy in enemies:
        if -320 <= enemy.ycor() <= 320 and enemy.xcor() >= -320:
            pass  # still on the screen
        else:
            enemy.hideturtle()
            enemies.pop(enemies.index(enemy))

        move(enemy)
        enemy_direction(enemy)
        wn.update()

    if enemies:
        wn.ontimer(move_all, 100)  # still enemies left to move
    else:
        wn.tracer(True)  # all done, restore normal graphics mode

move_all()

wn.mainloop()
```

I'm assuming you wrote too much code before testing it and were left with an impossible debugging task.  Write small sections, test them, and then build up.